# WCF protobuf-net endpoint in Code

Tags: c#, wcf

I want inizialize wcf client inside my code instead use app.config.

The main problem is i don't have idea how move protobuf support from my App.config to my code.
I need this cause is more userfull manage changes inside code, consider also if i update service reference it will overwrite app.config and it is not good.

My example:

```
WSHttpBinding clientBinding = new WSHttpBinding();
clientBinding.Security.Mode = SecurityMode.None;
clientBinding.MaxReceivedMessageSize = 10000000;
const string _serverlink = "http://localhost:56142/SimpleService.svc";

using (TestClient client = new TestClient (clientBinding, new EndpointAddress(_serverlink )))
{ //do something }
```

App.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1" />
    </startup>
    <system.serviceModel>
      <behaviors>
        <endpointBehaviors>
          <behavior name="protoEndpointBehavior">
            <protobuf/>
          </behavior>
        </endpointBehaviors>
        <serviceBehaviors>
          <behavior>
            <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="false" httpsGetEnabled="false"/>
            <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
          </behavior>
        </serviceBehaviors>
      </behaviors>

        <bindings>
          <wsHttpBinding>
            <binding name="WSHttpBinding_ISimpleService" maxBufferPoolSize="20097152" maxReceivedMessageSize="20097152">
              <security mode="None"/>
            </binding>
          </wsHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <client>
            <endpoint address="http://localhost:56142/SimpleService.svc" behaviorConfiguration="protoEndpointBehavior"
                binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="WSHttpBinding_ISimpleService"
                contract="SimpleHttp.ISimpleService" name="WSHttpBinding_ISimpleService">
                <identity>
                    <dns value="localhost" />
                </identity>
            </endpoint>
        </client>

      <extensions>
        <behaviorExtensions>
          <add name="protobuf" type="ProtoBuf.ServiceModel.ProtoBehaviorExtension, protobuf-net, Version=2.0.0.668, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=257b51d87d2e4d67"/>
        </behaviorExtensions>
      </extensions>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```